# How to run external Python script in Golang?

Tags: python, go, cmd, exec, external

I would like to run an external Python script that gets 4 arguments. If I would like to run the Python script in cmd it would look like this: python Required\Python\screenshot.py-master\screenshot.py --nojs -thumb http://google.com/ Required\Images\Screenshots\google.jpg
So, I would like to run this command from Go.
How could I implement this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do the examples in the docs help? https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/

Comment: nope, unfortunately I searched everywhere for some info but I can't run that Python script from Go

Comment: If following the documentation doesn't help, you need to show what you've tried that isn't working, what the error is, and what you expect to happen. Otherwise we're just rewriting the same examples from the docs.

Comment: You seem to be using windows - are those paths correctly escaped?

Answer (score 2):

If examples from doc are not helpful, maybe this will make it easier for you.

test.go:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    log.Println(os.Args)
    if len(os.Args) == 1 {
        return
    }
    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[1], os.Args[2:]...)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    log.Println(cmd.Run())
}
```

test.py:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

usage:

```
$ go run test.go python test.py 1 two 3 four
2016/02/20 21:45:42 [/tmp/go-build772613382/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/test python test.py 1 two 3 four]
['test.py', '1', 'two', '3', 'four']
2016/02/20 21:45:42 <nil>
```